# Multiple NodeJS instance on Azure App Service

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-appservice

As captioned, can I run multiple NodeJS instances in a single Azure App Services?

e.g.:

```
wwwroot/node1/xxx
wwwroot/node2/yyy
```

So, when I access `xx.xx/note1/**` it will go to node 1 instance.

As I don't want to huge NodeJS project and would like to break into multiple small projects, but using a single App Services.

From the Azure DevOps pipeline seems there is no way to allow me to deploy NodeJS other than the root folder, i.e. `wwwroot/`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

First, deploy multiple apps to single web app using Virtual directory. In this case you will have https://yourdomain/app1, https://yourdomain/app2. Go to you App Service -> Configuration -> Path Mappings

[image]

When you deploy you will need to specify **VirtualApplication** for you application this will let to deploy in [correct folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/webapp?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#deploy-to-a-virtual-application).

Second, you can have multiple Web Apps under single **App Service Plan** in this case it will be more isolated but still will pay same price as in first option. But you will have two different Web Apps, With two different url